# How to deal with offset between dynamic and static array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm making a Google Sheet for my discord community (short: *guild*) and I have a **row**/or **header** (depends on sheet) where I import all of my guild members via function `=importJSON()` or `={ListName!Area}` for example:

[image]

So the problem is: when someone leaves or joins the guild the whole user-input-data (**B** column and so on) becomes obsolete because of the offset.

Yes, I could use `=SORT/=FILTER` to modify imported data, but how do I protect input area data and connected the certain row/column to a certain member? So even if someone leaves or joins this array, input data still be relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way is to implement `VLOOKUP` function with a common value wrapped into `ARRAYFORMULA`. eg. something like this:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A; Sheet1!A:B; 2; 0)))
```

which translates as: if a value in A1:A is found in range Sheet1:A:B bring up data from a 2nd column of Sheet1:A:B

example:

[image]

Comment: in essence... a common practice is to use unique IDs as the link between two arrays like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L2f0.gif